# Can the active player choose the order of simultaneous effects?

Tags: android-netrunner

I am the runner.

I have a [Femme Fatale](http://www.cardgamedb.com/index.php/netrunner/android-netrunner-card-spoilers/_/core/femme-fatale-core) that targets a [Data Raven](http://www.cardgamedb.com/index.php/netrunner/android-netrunner-card-spoilers/_/core/data-raven-core) and make a run on a server that is protected by that Data Raven.

When I encouter the Data Raven, both cards trigger (*When you encounter that ice*.../*When the Runner encounters Data Raven*...).

Can I choose in which order the effects apply (so I can choose to take the tag from Data Raven, *then* bypass it with Femme Fatale)?

Or is the order of effects fixed (first the effects of runner cards, then the effects of corporation cards, since it's the runner's turn)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The order is fixed. First the active player (the one who's turn it is) chooses the order for their own simultaneous effects (if any) then the other player chooses the order for theirs.

So no, you cannot take the tag and then bypass, you *must* bypass first, or not bypass and take the tag.

Comment: can you point me to the right section in the rules?

Comment: Its in the section about simultaneous conditional effects, somewhat towards the back of the rule book IIRC.

Comment: *Simultaneous Effects*, page 22.